# equivalent of ZipEntry in directory use context

Tags: java, directory, zip, fuse

What's the equivalent of a ZipEntry in a directory use context ?
I'm trying to replace a code written for zipfiles to convert it into a code written for directories instead.

Answer (score 0):

As a `ZipEntry` represents a file, I guess you are looking for [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).